# Create a WOPI Frame link to a file

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to create a link to a document through a WOPI Frame (apologies if my terminology is terrible).

The URL to my file is: `https://mydomain/sites/mysite/Documents/myfilename.vsdx`

When I try to use: `https://mydomain/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/WopiFrame2.aspx?sourcedoc=https://mydomain/sites/mysite/Documents/myfilename.vsdx` (I am told that for some reason the right URL is WopiFrame2, not just Wopiframe, though going through just Wopiframe gives the same result) I just get to the root folder where my document is.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On-premises does not support Visio in Office Online Server so this will not be possible. Visio Graphics Services is what can display a Visio document in the browser, however it also requires Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in fact trying to show a VSDX file, I think that's the issues. If memory servers, WOPI has no function for Visio files. This is because Visio is a service application available at the Enterprise Lic level.

To verify my guess, you should test the same code with a Excel or Word file.

PS To simply create a link, I've used "https://site/library/file1.docx?web=1"

Comment: So this works for docx files. The instructions I trying to follow are here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-Visio-visualizations-to-Power-BI-reports-4F09BE62-F436-45C2-93B0-4A0F66B1F5A7 (specifically step 5). Do you see a way to do it? Also, from what you are saying, it doesn't matter if its a .vsd file instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (took out 2 and added &action=default at the end

https://mydomain/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=https://mydomain/sites/mysite/Documents/myfilename.vsdx&action=default